# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader, status 502

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postgresql, cors, fetch

I am having the following errors
[error fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgfc.png)

[error consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92MXV.png)

[back-in-render.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qldkv.png)

my code is as follows:

`ProtectRouterAdmin.jsx`:

```
const handle = useCallback( async () => {
        getInfo(token).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                res.json()
            } else {
                console.log("Error get")
            }
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[token])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {
            handle()
        }else{
            setNavitate(<Navigate to={"/"} replace />)
        }
    }, [])
```

`Peticion.js`

```
async function getInfo(token) {
    const response = await fetch(`${ur}/get-infoUser`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': token
        }
    })
    return response
}
```

`UserRouter.js`

```
async function auth(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let token = req.headers['Authorization'];
        let resultadoToken = jwt.verify(token, '@111233');
        let usuario = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: resultadoToken.id
            },
            attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
        });
        req.user = usuario;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        req.err = err
    }
}

router.get("/get-infoUser", auth, async (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
        const user = req.user
        res.json(user)
    }else{
        res.json({error: res.err})
    }
})
```

`index.js`

```
const Express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = Express()
const path = require("path")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()
const routes = require("./routes/index.js")

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.use(Express.json())
app.use('/images', Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
routes(app)


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hola")
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Corriendo en el puesto 4000")
})
```

**I am providing all the context of my code since I don't know what could be producing those errors that I am having

I hope you can please help me**

I tried adding the following, but nothing

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

Comment: post error messages as text (code), not url image